# Makefile possibly wrong, undefined reference to function in C

Tags: c, makefile, terminal, compiler-errors, compilation

Trying to compile my program which has three source files called `hencode.c`, `hdecode.c` and `htable.c`. The `htable.c` file contains all the functions that the former two files use and the `htable.h` file contains the prototypes. This is my Makefile, but I keep getting an `undefined reference to 'function'` error on the terminal.

Neither files are compiling correctly.
I use this command to compile the file: `gcc -o hdecode -Wall -ansi -pedantic hdecode.c`

I have no idea what is wrong. I have included `"htable.h"` in all my files. I think the error might be in the Makefile but I cannot spot it. Thank you for any help.

Here is my Makefile:

```
CC      = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -ansi -pedantic -g -std=c99
LD      = gcc

all: hdecode hencode

hdecode: htable.o hdecode.o
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) htable.o hdecode.o -o hdecode

hencode: htable.o hencode.o
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) htable.o hencode.o -o hencode

hdecode.o: hdecode.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c hdecode.c

hencode.o: hencode.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c hencode.c

htable.o: htable.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c htable.c

clean:
    @rm *.o hdecode hencode
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please (re)read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon, but more importantly, please read about how to create an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) or 
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).

Comment: Which function is reported as missing?  Which source file is it defined in?  How were we supposed to guess that? When asking questions about linking errors, please include the actual error message (or perhaps the first message for each function, for the first few functions).  Without that information, it is impossible to help you much.  With that information, it is probably easy to help.  For example, if the missing function is a standard function such as `sqrt()`, we can diagnose that you need the maths library (usually `-lm` on systems where it is needed at all).

Answer (score 0):

> Trying to compile my program which has two source files called `hencode.c` and `hdecode.c`. The `htable.c` file contains all the functions that the two files both use and the `htable.h` file contains the prototypes.

Note that your program is composed of *three* source files, not two. When linking the final program, you need to have the symbols defined in `htable.c` available. In other words, `#include`-ing a file does not automatically compile nor link it in the final program.

> My `hencode` file is compiling correctly, however my `hdecode` file is not. I use this command to compile the file: `gcc -o hdecode -Wall -ansi -pedantic hdecode.c`

This is unclear -- are you using the Makefile or compiling manually? If it is the latter, you need to pass both source files (or object files if previously compiled):

```
# Note the added htable.c
gcc -o hdecode -Wall -ansi -pedantic htable.c hdecode.c
```

Finally, also note that the Makefile can be simplified:

```
CC      = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -ansi -pedantic -g -std=c99

all: hdecode hencode

hdecode: htable.o hdecode.o
hencode: htable.o hencode.o
hdecode.o: hdecode.c
hencode.o: hencode.c
htable.o: htable.c

clean:
    @rm *.o hdecode hencode
```

Comment: I am using the Makefile

Comment: @AmyWilson: In that case, it looks like the problem is in the code.